# JQuery button click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JQuery and my problem is that I have a button in a modal such that when I click it, a JQuery script is run. Pieces of code so far:

```
<a id="submitMe" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Submit</a>       

$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#submitMe").click(function(){
         alert("Something to alert");
    });
});
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Did you wrap your javascript code in script tags?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: They are wrapped in script tags, sorry, I didn't show that part.

Comment: @Paldan don't use anchors for buttons, use span instead or input type button. 1st If you using anchors without `href` attribute that's invalid 2nd If you use anchors you must prevent default action.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, make sure you've included jQuery properly. You should download jQuery and place it in you folder and import it at you html source or use below inline query src definition to access the library online.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Secondly, if your anchor has been added dynamically to the DOM, you need to use event delegation:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click','#submitMe',function() {
    alert("Something to alert");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Two click handlers in one?

Comment: You are nesting handlers here and document ready handler is useless

Comment: 20K `click` in `on`? Is that make sense?

Comment: @putvande & Rohan Kumar My bad :/ I have some urgent stuffs just now :P